# minimum user permissions required for alter table in ssms

Tags: sql-server, ssms, user-permissions

Initially I could do everything in SSMS graphically, but now I am unable to **ALTER table**, create a **KEY** and **CONSTRAINTS**. I get the error message : "**Unspecified error (MS Visual database Tools)**". I only can do this now by TSQL.

I believe that my permissions were changed! I think I had permission db_owner and now I have
db_ddladmin, db_datareader and db_datawriter.

It's possible to do the commands above graphically with different permissions without having db_owner permission?

[image]

Regards
Elio

Answer (score 0):

check under tools/options/designers/table and database designers

the option "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" must be off

Comment: The option "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" was already is off. thanks anyway.

Comment: if you take the script generated by SSMS after you change the table, and try run it what happens?

Comment: Update the post with an image. The  Script option "ALTER To" is disabled.